# Using environment variables in a definition of another environment variable

Tags: java, windows-7

I am trying to run the Java compiler, javac.exe, from the command line without qualifying the path to the exe. To do so, I knew that the path to this exe had to be included in my %path% system environment variable. The location of the exe on my macghine is: C:\Program Files (x86)\SQLLIB\java\jdk\bin; However, since I knew that the length of this env variable was already at its max length, 2048, I decided to make use of another system environment variable, %JAVA_HOME%, which was already set to C:\Program Files (x86)\SQLLIB\java\jdk, so I added %JAVA_HOME%\bin; to the very beginning of my path.

However, when I tried to run the java compiler javac from the command line, I found that the command line interpreter could not locate the exe using my updated path. Although everything that I've seen suggested to me that a reboot was not necessary only closing and re-opening the cmd window, I nevertheless rebooted to no avail. When I changed my PATH variable to not use an embedded %JAVA_HOME% variable, repklacing %JAVA_HOME%\bin with C:\Program Files (x86)\SQLLIB\java\jdk\bin, (i.e. explicitly spelling out the complete path to the compiler) and tried once more to run the compiler simply by referencing the name of the compiler file, javac, it worked.

In general, I expected that this would work. In fact, I was even tempted to to build my Path by defining in a new env variable, "PATH1", and then redefine PATH = C:\Program Files (x86)\SQLLIB\java\jdk;%PATH1% as discussed here:

http://www.charlesrcook.com/archive/2012/08/27/path-environment-variable-too-long-and-truncated.aspx

...but I wasn't so daring and decided that what I tried was more modest but had the same concept of nesting the definition of  evariables.

My question is, why didn't this work? Did it have something to do with the fact that the path had an embedded space in it? If so, I wouldn't know where quotes would be deployed to correct it. Is nesting variables even safe? I could imagine that the order in which they are evaluated could get complex...

I am brand spanking new to java, but after two days of trying to config various dev apps that use java I am really turned off at how central environent variables seem to be in configuration. I'll try to withhold judgement until I get a better understanding...

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\SQLLIB\java\jdk
```

Works:

```
PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\SQLLIB\java\jdk\bin; c:\Whatever
```

Does not work, But why not?

```
PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;c:\Whatever
```

Comment: and tried once more to run the compiler simply by referencing the name of the file, it worked, --- didn't get that part, what is the file name that u used ?  usually javac expects a .java file to compile. something like javac MyMainProgram.java, if not u can use flags -help / -version to get some info.

Comment: Windows not always but sometimes has a problem with spaces in its path. for that we usually replace  Program Files (x86) with PROGRA~2 implicit directory shortcut known already. So ur C:\Program Files (x86)\SQLLIB\java\jdk becomes C:\PROGRA~2\SQLLIB\java\jdk

Comment: @  Arkantos: I rephrased that sentence to hopefully make it more clear.

Comment: i know this sounds stupid, but u don't have %JAVA_HOME% as ur new variable rt ? ;) it should be just JAVA_HOME and when ur referring that in ur path, its %JAVA_HOME%\bin; - ends with a semi colon prepended to ur  path variable

Comment: @Arkantos:See my edit. I think the PATH  should include the bin subfolder, since that's where the JAVAC file resides

Comment: What you want to work should work just fine... what is the output of `echo %PATH%` after you do `PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;c:\Whatever`

Comment: Are you manipulating the path via the gui in windows or somehow else? Did you every try to directly modify it in the registry?

Comment: @Syberdoor: Via the GUI